# Cannot get custom user id, with laravel auditing

Tags: laravel

I have added the laravel auditable in my laravel version 6.9.0. I have tried to this problem many time but not working properly. I added in my **User** model. The ***user_id*** consists of numbers of letters and special characters. see the example of ***user_id*** in following.

`user_id = '2020JANAAUSER-001'`

In **User** Model.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements Auditable
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'active',
        'role_id'
    ];
...
```

the  `user_id` datatype is `varchar(32)`.

see in following picture from **audits** table.

[image: here is the image.]

see the 2020 in `user_id` its not my `user_id` format.

Its the **migration** for `create_users_table` .

```
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('user_id', 32)->unique();
            $table->string('username', 32)->unique();
            $table->string('name', 32);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('role_id', 32);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('role_id')->on('role');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the migration for `create_users_table.php`?

Comment: I have added the migration.

Comment: can you show me that file?

Comment: i have added in last part of question.

Comment: what `2020JANAAUSER-001` stands for? is it from the docs?

Comment: It’s my custom format and stand for 2020 January term AA Id type is USER and number of Id is 001

Comment: I hope got my answer.